# ReactJS using Ionic Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined from axios request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ionic-framework, axios

I got a `schedules.ts` file and I got a function `getSchedules()`

```
import axios from 'axios'

export default function getSchedules(){
    const config = {
        headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('bearer_token') ,
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        }
    };
     return axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/auth/getSchedules',config).
      then((res)=>{
       return res.data
      }).catch((err)=>{
        console.log(err)
      })
}
```

In my Tab1 component, I want to get the data from my axios request and display by using array.map

```
import getSchedules from '../methods/schedules'

const Tab1: React.FC = () => {

  const [schedules, setSchedules] = React.useState([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    getSchedules().then(data => setSchedules(data.schedules));
  }, []);


  return (
    <IonPage>
      <IonHeader>
        <IonToolbar>
          <IonTitle>Appointments</IonTitle>
        </IonToolbar>
      </IonHeader>
      <IonContent className="ion-padding">
    <IonList>

      {schedules.map(elem => {
        return(
          <IonItem key={elem['id']}>
          <IonLabel>
            <h2>{elem['schedule_type']}</h2>
            <h3>{elem['type']}</h3>
            <h3>{elem['start_date']}</h3>
          </IonLabel>
        </IonItem> 
        )
      })}

    </IonList>
  </IonContent>
    </IonPage>
  );
};
export default Tab1;
```

But when I go to the component I got

`Tab1.tsx:38 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`

I am new to react and this typescript thing. I wish i can use `v-for` like in vue.js. Can someone tell me what is the problem of this and how can I solve? Thanks..

Comment: `schedules` is undefined. Try logging out the return of `getSchedules`

Comment: here is the log output @Baruch https://imgur.com/a/7hGPKe8

Comment: @Vince where did you console log? In Tab1 or when you call the function?

Comment: inside `React.useEffect(()` @Ryan

Comment: @Vince did you console.log data.schedules or data?

Comment: i just do `console.log(getSchedules());` inseide `React.useEffect` as what Brauch said @Ryan

Comment: So there is no `schedules` property, and you should just pass `data` to `setSchedules`

Comment: @Vince try ```console.log(data.schedules)```, is that undefined?

Comment: where should i `console.log(data.schedules)` ? inside `useEffect`? If i do i got error `Cannot find name data ts(2304)` @Ryan

Comment: what do you mean @RobinZigmond?

Comment: `getSchedules().then(data => setSchedules(data.schedules));` - according to your screenshot, there is no `schedules` property, so `data.schedules` is `undefined`. I suspect you want just `getSchedules().then(data => setSchedules(data));`

Comment: seems `getSchedules().then(data => setSchedules(data))` works for me. Thank you for this @RobinZigmond. Can you explain further in the answer section? Thanks..

Comment: OK I will put this as an answer, although there's really no more to say that hasn't already been.

Comment: okay please. thanks a lot @RobinZigmond

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem turned out to be that the `data` coming back from the API had no `schedules` property, so `setSchedules(data.schedules)` is making `schedules` `undefined`. The data as a whole is already the desired array, so what is needed is to call `setSchedules` with `data` as the argument.

That is, the body of `useEffect` should be

```
getSchedules().then(data => setSchedules(data));
```

which can, if you prefer, be simplified as

```
getSchedules().then(setSchedules);
```